# How to Differentiate Between Numerical and Alphabetical Input

Tags: c++, integer

I was wondering, how would I be able to compare a variable which is supposed to hold integer values, to times when it is passed a char value:
For example:

```
int i;
cin >> i;
if(i == integer)
          execute a command;
else (if i == char)
          do something else here;
```

Since x can't hold a character value, would it just fail when someone tries to input a character value in i?

Comment: Check the result of the input operation to see whether it succeeded.

Comment: It sounds like your question is really: "What happens if I do `int i; cin >> i;` and someone types in something that's not an integer?"

Comment: Look into ctype: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/ctype/is/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get input into a string, then *try* to convert it to an integer (you have a myriad of options here, `boost::lexical_cast`, `std::istringstream`, `std::stoi`, etc...).  If the conversion succeeds, you have an integer, if it fails, you don't.  Here's an example using `istringstream`:

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
std::istringstream iss(input);
int x;
if (iss >> x)
{
    // success
}
else
{
    // failure
}
```

If you don't care what the input was in the case that it wasn't an integer, you can just check for failure directly on input into an `int`:

```
int x;
if (cin >> x)
{
    // success
}
else
{
    // get cin out of the error state
    cin.clear();
}
```

Comment: So if I want for i to be an input for an integer, can I do: if(i = = true) execute command else do something else

Comment: @Josh: What?  No. I showed you what to do.  Is there something in my example you don't understand?

Answer (score 2):

Use **ctype.h** functions to check the type of the variable.
You should get something like this:

```
char i;
cin >> i;

if(isdigit(i))
{
 // if integer
}
else if(isalpha(i))
{
 //if character
}
```